# jQuery re-rendering/painting bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, rendering, marionette

I am have a very odd issue in jQuery while using Marionette and Backbone.

I am rendering a collection using a Marionette CollectionView. My collection has objects that can be clicked on and added to another collection, at which time I want to hide the element of the original collection.

At certain window sizes, clicking on a seemingly random amount of these 'add' buttons will cause jQuery to repaint the screen very strangely, hiding certain elements. Resizing the window fixes this or taking any other action within the window fixes it.

This is what it should look like normally
[image: normal]

And this is what clicking on a few of the 'add' buttons does 
[image: dumb]

EDIT: The code that invokes the jQuery to hide the element is as follows

```
addFeed: (e) =>
  App.vent.trigger("topic:edited", true)
  e.preventDefault() if e
  if @tip
    @tip.remove()
  @$el.hide()
  @trigger('add')
```

EDIT 2:

```
addFeed: (view) =>
  App.vent.trigger("topic:edited", true)

  feed = new Backstitch.Models.TopicFeed()

  feed.set "name" : view.model.get("name")
  feed.set "icon" : view.model.get("icon")
  feed.set "ignore_global_filters" : false

  if view.model.get('service') && view.model.get('service').get('set_origin_icon')
    feed.set "origin_icon": view.model.get('service').get('icon')

  @model.get("feeds").add(feed)

  if view.model.get("id")
    @subscribeToFeed(view, feed)
  else
    @createNewFeed(view, feed)


createNewFeed: (view, feed) =>
  view.model.save {},
    success: (model) =>
      view.model.set "id": model.get("id")
      @subscribeToFeed(view, feed)
    error: (model, response) =>
      App.vent.trigger "error",
        module: "TopicFeedsCatalog"
        activity: "SearchResultLayout#createNewFeed"
        response: response

subscribeToFeed: (view, feed) =>
  feed.save { 
    topic: @model,
    feed_id: view.model.get("id")
  },
  success: (feed) =>
    App.vent.trigger("addedFeed", feed)

  error: (model, response) =>
    App.vent.trigger "error",
      module: "TopicFeedsCatalog"
      activity: "SearchResultLayout#subscribeToFeed"
      response: response
```

Comment: Please post the code that invokes jQuery

Comment: @seebiscuit I just edited wit hthe code that invokes the jQuery.

Comment: How about the handler for the `'add'` event?

Comment: Sorry Tommy. I can't really see much from the code you posted. I still don't see how things connect, or where you're invoking a render (I only see models, which Marionette does not automatically bind change events to render...).

Comment: @seebiscuit That's okay. It's hard to ask for help on this because the module is pretty complex. Thanks for at least looking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something wrong is happening with the wrapper/container element of lists.